# Recaptcha onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, recaptcha

I want to fire a jQuery event onclick when the user selects the recaptcha checkbox.

This is the code I have:

```
<div id="reCaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
```

Is this possible to do? I've tried the usual jQuery onclick event (see below) for that element but to no avail.

```
$j('#reCaptcha').on('click', function(event) { 
    alert("YES PLEASE!");
});
```

Comment: Try `$j(document).on("click", "#reCaptchah", function() { alert("clicked"); });`

Comment: @freedomn-m, no doesnt work unfortunately. The captcha puzzle thing pops out but not alert

Comment: (did you try it without my typo (just noticed it))?

Comment: Yes without the typo it just executed the puzzle layer and nothing else. No alert

Comment: Can you create a simple working fiddle for us? Any errors in the dev console? Also please share a bit of background to let us know the reason to try to add a click (maybe we can find a better approach or adjust for an alternative)

Answer (score 0):

reCaptcha have callback function which you can provide by using data
as eg

```
<div id="reCaptcha" data-callback="thecallback"
 data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
```

then you can write you call back after click

```
function thecallback(){
alert("Clicked")
}
```

that is what is legally possible hp[e it will help you

Comment: Is this call back when they have completed the puzzle? Because no matter what I try the alert isnt coming on click.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display please check this link 
data-callback. The name of your callback function, executed when the user submits a successful response, also you will have data-expired-callback + data-error-callback

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="reCaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX"></div>
```

Then:

```
$j('#reCaptcha').on('click', function(event) { 
    alert("Your code works!");
});
```